# build_depend for eigen3, kinetic in package.xml

Tags: eigen, catkin, ros-kinetic, package.xml, eigen3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am using eigen3 in my node. So I added the following statement to my *CMakeLists.txt*

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

but what should I add to the *package.xml*, eigen3 or eigen?

```
<build_depend>eigen</build_depend>
```

or

```
<build_depend>eigen3</build_depend>
```

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247968/build_depend-for-eigen3,-kinetic-in-package.xml/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2016-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at [ros/rosdistro/rosdep/base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/1a9fda299e71f1b0dbe670516420fb05986b7214/rosdep/base.yaml), the `eigen` key maps to Eigen 3 ([here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/1a9fda299e71f1b0dbe670516420fb05986b7214/rosdep/base.yaml#L667-L685)), `eigen2` maps to Eigen 2 ([here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/1a9fda299e71f1b0dbe670516420fb05986b7214/rosdep/base.yaml#L686-L692)) and the `eigen3` mapping ([here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/1a9fda299e71f1b0dbe670516420fb05986b7214/rosdep/base.yaml#L693-L697)) is a bit ambiguous and incomplete (perhaps @tfoote can explain that one).

If you don't need v2, you should just depend on `eigen`, otherwise on `eigen2`.

Note btw that (at least in Indigo and Jade) in addition to `build_depend`ing on `eigen`, you should also add a `build_depend` on `cmake_modules` to be able to use `find_package(Eigen3 ..)`, as that package provides the find script for it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2016-11-14**:
Thanks that way the answer I was looking for.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-11-14**:
The eigen3 target looks to be a sweeping gentoo fixup followed by a sweeping fedora fedora fixup. [gentoo](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/5507d623fae9da5936f8786823f3bd356d57141b) [fedora](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/77ffdb78d013d5714407085daca6675c2859ccf0)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-11-14**:
They should be merged into the eigen target and eigen3 removed since that's the one used for all the other platforms. https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/13200